# Parse data/numbers from table cells C# or VisualBasic

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, parsing, html-table

I have a string which contains html code from a webpage. There's a table in the code I'm interested in. I want to parse the numbers present in the table cells and put them in textboxes, each number in its own textbox. Here's the table:

```
<table class="tblSkills">
    <tr>
        <th class="th_first">Strength</th><td class="align_center">15</td>
        <th>Passing</th><td class="align_center">17</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="th_first">Stamina</th><td class="align_center">16</td>
        <th>Crossing</th><td class="align_center"><img src='/pics/star.png' alt='20' title='20' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="th_first">Pace</th><td class="align_center"><img src='/pics/star_silver.png' alt='19' title='19' /></td>
        <th>Technique</th><td class="align_center">16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="th_first">Marking</th><td class="align_center">15</td>
        <th>Heading</th><td class="align_center">10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="th_first">Tackling</th><td class="align_center"><span class='subtle'>5</span></td>
        <th>Finishing</th><td class="align_center">15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="th_first">Workrate</th><td class="align_center">16</td>
        <th>Longshots</th><td class="align_center">8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="th_first">Positioning</th><td class="align_center">18</td>
        <th>Set Pieces</th><td class="align_center"><span class='subtle'>2</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

As you can see there are 14 numbers. To make things worse numbers like 19 and 20 are replaced by images and numbers lower than 6 have a span class.
I know I could use HTML agility pack or something similar, but I'm not yet that good to figure how to do it by myself, so I need your help.

Comment: Yes, Html Agility Pack would be a good choice. Have you even *tried* to use it? What code do you have so far?

Comment: So you'd prefer a Regex solution to the problem?

Comment: I tried RegularExpressions. I don't have enough points to post any code.
@Josh: It's not that I prefer this or that, I want it to work, just tried something and I think it can't be done with Regex.

Comment: string text = "...";
string pattern = @"\d+";

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(text, pattern))
{
  string x = m.ToString();                      
}

Comment: <td class="align_center"><img src='/pics/star_silver.png' alt='19' title='19' /></td>

I only need one 19 out of this image, not two. How can I filter it out???

Comment: a solution:

string pattern = @"((?<=\>)\d+)|((?<=alt\=')\d+)";

Comment: Now I need to figure out hot to parse only the data inside the table. How can I filter out everything else but the table???????????????

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML sample also happens to be good XML. You could use any of .net's XML reading/parsing techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ to XML in C#:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(yourHtml);

var properties = new List<string>(
    from th in doc.Descendants("th")
    select th.Value);

var values = new List<int>(
    from td in doc.Descendants("td")
    let img = td.Element("img")
    let textValue = img == null ? td.Value : img.Attribute("alt").Value
    select int.Parse(textValue));

var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
for (var i = 0; i < properties.Count; i++)
{
    dict[properties[i]] = values[i];
}
```